# Drawer Menu from JSON not showing items

Tags: java, android, json

```
    public static List<NavItem> configuration() {

            final List<NavItem> i = new ArrayList<NavItem>();

            //DONT MODIFY ABOVE THIS LINE
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            RequestHandle items = client.get("myurl", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onStart() {
                                    // called before request is started
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {

                                    String result = new String(response);


                                    JSONObject obj = null;
                                    JSONArray arr = null;
                                    try {
                                            obj = new JSONObject(result);
                                            arr = obj.getJSONArray("items");
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    for (int s = 0; s < arr.length(); s++) {
                                            String pltitle = null;
                                            String plid = null;
                                            try {
                                                    pltitle = arr.getJSONObject(s).getJSONObject("snippet").getString("title");
                                                    plid = arr.getJSONObject(s).getString("id");

                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                            i.add(new NavItem(pltitle, R.drawable.icon_play, NavItem.ITEM, VideosFragment.class, plid + ",channelid"));


                                    }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure ( int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                                                    byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e){
                                    // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onRetry ( int retryNo){
                                    // called when request is retried
                            }
                    }

            );

            i.add(new NavItem("Tüm Videolar", R.drawable.icon_star, NavItem.EXTRA, VideosFragment.class, "asf"));
            i.add(new NavItem("Facebook",R.drawable.icon_fb, NavItem.EXTRA, FacebookFragment.class, "asd"));
            i.add(new NavItem("Twitter",R.drawable.icon_tw, NavItem.EXTRA, TweetsFragment.class, "asd"));
            i.add(new NavItem("Favoriler", R.drawable.ic_action_favorite, NavItem.EXTRA, FavFragment.class, null));
            i.add(new NavItem("Oynatma Listeleri", NavItem.SECTION));



            //It's Suggested to not change the content below this line


   // i.add(new NavItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings, NavItem.EXTRA, SettingsFragment.class, null)); */

            //DONT MODIFY BELOW THIS LINE

        return i;

    }
```

My app uses this `config.java` to build drawer menu its actually static menu but I make some customizations and make it take data from json but after it takes data its not showing on drawer but when I'm touch an item on drawer the data appears I think its refreshing it self how can I make it auto refresh when data took?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that you get drawer data form an AsyncHttpClient. It will execute and call onSuccess() later. So function configuration() only return Tüm Videolar, Facebook, Twitter, Favoriler, Oynatma Listeleri.

For this, please call notifyDataSetChanged() of your menu adapter at the end of onSuccess().

Comment: My menu adapter is in another java this is the all codes of config.java can you write full code of this java or another way to do that and thanks for answer